# Why would a cat refuse to eat any kind of wet food?

Tags: cats, diet

We moved recently with 2 cats. Both were former strays and would devour anything you'd put down for them to eat. Especially wet food.

After settling in, one of them suddenly stopped eating any kind of wet food. I tried different flavours, brands, heating etc. No luck, just takes a sniff and moves on. He also refused to eat their regular dry food. Had to change the brand and managed to find one that he eats.

Looks like he's eating a decent amount of dry food but still would not touch canned stuff.

What can I do to bring his appetite back?

Edit: Just captured him doing it again: http://d.ekin.io/1hmnA+ He ate the dry food on center and tried to bury the canned food in the small cups.

Comment: You're sure their bowls are clean, right?

Comment: Yeah we use porcelain cups actually, not bowls. Regularly washing in the dishwasher.

Comment: @keshlam: also, additional video: http://d.ekin.io/1hmnA+

Comment: It may be worth getting his teeth checked - sometimes increased pickiness is a medical thing.  (admittedly, sometimes it's just a cat thing.  Cats often seem to like to demand different foods )